# How can i migrate changes in my strapi collection types from development to production

Tags: strapi

I am using strapi v4. I create a few collection types in my development environment.  Then i deploy my instance to production.  After this I add change my collection types in development. How can i deploy these changes to production?

Comment: Model changes are stored in the file system, so you push them with git push… Then you pull. Content however stored in the database,and uploads folder

Comment: That's ok, my question was how to deploy database changes that result from collection type changes. Somebody pointed out ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71980495/how-to-deploy-changes-to-production-without-downtime-generic-hosting?rq=2) that this happens automatically as soon as the code changes are incorporated in production. Might try this ...

Comment: Yea if the concern is persisting database after mutation you might wanna look on migration scripts https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/database-migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody pointed out ([How to deploy changes to production without downtime (generic hosting)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71980495/how-to-deploy-changes-to-production-without-downtime-generic-hosting?rq=2)) that as soon as  the updated code is deployed, the database changes are applied automatically. Tried that and it works. Great!